# I am using two IN and OUT param in store procedure where I am getting two result, I want the two result in PHP

Tags: php, stored-procedures

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `prev1`(IN `page` INT(50), OUT `foundrows` INT(255))
BEGIN DECLARE foundrows varchar(255);
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  * FROM studentmarks limit page ,6;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()as foundrows;
END
```

this is my php code

```
$pag=$_GET["offset"];
$sql="call prev1($pag,@foundrows)";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

and my response is

```
mysqli_result Object
(    [current_field] => 0  
  [field_count] => 13   
 [lengths] =>   
  [num_rows] => 6   
 [type] => 0
)
```

but my found_rows is not  getting in php. but my total found_rows is 19 but is showing only  [num_rows] => 6

Comment: what you mean "but my found_rows is getting in php." ? can you be more specific ?

Comment: but my found_rows is not getting in php. but my total found_rows is 19 but is showing only [num_rows] => 6

Comment: first , try direct sql query  with same values for be sure it is really 19.

Comment: yes its found_rows value is  19

Comment: can you try like that: `SELECT COUNT(*) as foundrows  FROM studentmarks limit page ,6;`

Comment: count is 19 in the above query

Comment: you have 6 record for each page. remove limitation and check it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return a value with a stored procedure:

**SQL :**

```
 DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE prev1(IN `page` INT, OUT `Out_val` INT)
 BEGIN
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  * FROM studentmarks limit page ,6;
    SELECT FOUND_ROWS() INTO Out_val;
 END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

 $pag = 1;
 $conn->multi_query("CALL prev1($pag,@Out_val);SELECT @Out_val as count");
do {
    /* store first result set */
    if ($result = $conn->store_result()) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            print_r($row);
        }
        $result->free();
    }
    /* print divider */
    if ($conn->more_results()) {
        printf("-----------------\n");
    }
} while ($conn->next_result());

?> 

</body>
</html>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: @vijaykumar I updated my answer, also I tested this code in my local system its working fine. Please check. 
Might u can try a standalone script separately in place of putting code in ur project.

Comment: hi.. I need two response 1) for limit query 2) and for  FOUND_ROWS() in same php

Comment: i am getting this error : Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_object() in